# query to flag a column based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to flag a column based on interdependent conditions. My input data is as below

| id | status | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Open | 1 |
| A | Delay | 2 |
| A | In | 3 |
| B | In | 1 |
| B | Out | 2 |
| B | Delay | 3 |
| B | count | 4 |
| C | In | 1 |
| C | Close | 2 |
| C | out | 3 |
| D | Close | 1 |
| D | Open | 2 |
| D | Delay | 3 |
| D | In | 4 |

My output should look like

| id | status | rnk | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Open | 1 | N |
| A | Delay | 2 | Y |
| A | In | 3 | N |
| B | In | 1 | N |
| B | Out | 2 | N |
| B | Delay | 3 | N |
| B | count | 4 | N |
| C | In | 1 | N |
| C | Close | 2 | N |
| C | out | 3 | N |
| D | Close | 1 | N |
| D | Open | 2 | N |
| D | Delay | 3 | Y |
| D | In | 4 | N |

Logic - if status column is anything other than Delay then the flag will be N.
If the status column is Delay and if the status is either 'Open' or 'Close' for records which are having less rnk than that of Delay within the same ID then flag will be Y else N.

Example - for ID 'A' we have a status 'Delay' and its rank is 2, now we need to check if the status of A with rank < 2 is either 'Open' or 'Close' then flag 'Delay' to 'Y'

please note: rnk column is already populated in the table based on different logic

Below is the query I have tried, but I am getting flag 'N' for all the records,

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE WHEN status != 'Delay' THEN 'N'
         WHEN rnk < (COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'Delay' THEN rnk ELSE -1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY id))) 
                         AND status IN ('Open','Close') THEN 'Y' 
         ELSE 'N'
    END AS flag 
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: What issues are you encountering?

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery is here more help full

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE WHEN status != 'Delay' THEN 'N'
         WHEN Exists( SELECT 1 FROM Table1 ta1 WHERE ta1.id = t1.id 
                         AND status IN ('Open','Close') AND ta1.rnk < t1.rnk) THEN 'Y' 
         ELSE 'N'
    END AS flag 
FROM Table1 t1
```

| id | status | rnk | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Open | 1 | N |
| A | Delay | 2 | Y |
| A | In | 3 | N |
| B | In | 1 | N |
| B | Out | 2 | N |
| B | Delay | 3 | N |
| B | count | 4 | N |
| C | In | 1 | N |
| C | Close | 2 | N |
| C | out | 3 | N |
| D | Close | 1 | N |
| D | Open | 2 | N |
| D | Delay | 3 | Y |
| D | In | 4 | N |

Answer (score 1):

Consider below simple approach

```
select *, if(
  status = 'Delay' and 
  countif(status in ('Open', 'Close')) over(partition by id order by rnk) > 0, 
  'Y', 'N') as flag
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use a grouped Common Table expression with the maximum rank and row count of all rows with status Open or Close, and left-join the base table with it:

```
-- your input, don't use in real query...
WITH
indata(id,status,rnk) AS (                                                                                                                                                                             
          SELECT 'A','Open',1
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','Delay',2
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','In',3
UNION ALL SELECT 'B','In',1
UNION ALL SELECT 'B','Out',2
UNION ALL SELECT 'B','Delay',3
UNION ALL SELECT 'B','count',4
UNION ALL SELECT 'C','In',1
UNION ALL SELECT 'C','Close',2
UNION ALL SELECT 'C','out',3
UNION ALL SELECT 'D','Close',1
UNION ALL SELECT 'D','Open',2
UNION ALL SELECT 'D','Delay',3
UNION ALL SELECT 'D','In',4
)
-- input ends here, real query starts below
-- replace following comma with "WITH" ...
,
prev_stats AS (
  SELECT
    id
  , MAX(rnk) AS rnk
  , COUNT(*) AS num
  FROM indata
  WHERE status IN ('Open','Close')
  GROUP BY id
)
SELECT
  indata.*
, CASE
    WHEN status <> 'Delay' THEN 'N'
    ELSE
     CASE
       WHEN prev_stats.num > 0 THEN 'Y'
       ELSE                         'N'
     END
  END AS flag
FROM indata
LEFT JOIN prev_stats ON indata.id = prev_stats.id
               AND indata.rnk > prev_stats.rnk
;
```

Result:

| id | status | rnk | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Open | 1 | N |
| A | Delay | 2 | Y |
| A | In | 3 | N |
| B | In | 1 | N |
| B | Out | 2 | N |
| B | Delay | 3 | N |
| B | count | 4 | N |
| C | In | 1 | N |
| C | Close | 2 | N |
| C | out | 3 | N |
| D | Close | 1 | N |
| D | Open | 2 | N |
| D | Delay | 3 | Y |
| D | In | 4 | N |